# JavascriptExecutor with document.evaluate xpath to change className

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I try to change class name in Java(webdriver, selenium) of
element:

```
<span class="myclass" role="button">mytext</span>
```

Java code:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0].className='clearr'");
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('mytext').className='clearr'");
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.evaluate('//span[@class='myclass'][text()='mytext']', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).className='clearr'");
```

1'st option is working good and change 1'st class 'myclass' name to 'clearr', but class 'myclass' is in many places and I need to use xpath=//*[@class='myclass'][text()='mytext']

2nd - I don't have fail but nothing happen. Still classname='myclass'

3th option: Fail

How can I make it work to get
element:

```
<span class="clearr" role="button">mytext</span>
```

Comment: Maybe `var all=document.getElementsByClassName('myclass'); var i=0; while(i<all.length){all[i].className='clearr';i++;}` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this approach: 
1. Locate your element using selenium locators like XPATH or so

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='myclass'][text()='mytext']");
```

2. Then use JavaScriptExecutor to change that class like this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].className='clearr'",element);
```